# How to convert a scipy csr_matrix back into lists of row, col and data?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy csr_matrix that was created this way as specified in the documentation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
mtr = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
mtr.toarray()
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

How do I efficiently convert such a matrix `mtr` back into the initial three lists `row`, `col` and `data`?

Answer (score 7):

As you noted in a comment, you can get the data by accessing the `data` attribute.  To get the rows and columns, you could convert the array to COO format, and access the `data`, `row` and `col` attributes:

Here's your array `mtr`:

```
In [11]: mtr
Out[11]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [12]: mtr.A
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

Convert to COO format, and access the `data`, `row` and `col` attributes.

```
In [13]: c = mtr.tocoo()

In [14]: c.data
Out[14]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64)

In [15]: c.row
Out[15]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)

In [16]: c.col
Out[16]: array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call [my_csr_matrix.nonzero()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero) followed by indexing.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
row = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
col = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
mtr = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))

print(mtr.todense())

rows, cols = mtr.nonzero()
data = mtr[rows, cols]

print(rows, cols, data)
```

Output:

```
[[1 0 2]
 [0 0 3]
 [4 5 6]]
[0 0 1 2 2 2] [0 2 2 0 1 2] [[1 2 3 4 5 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Also I have found that to get data I can use just `mtr.data`.

Comment: Yeah i was unsure about the order ```.data```, but it seems that should work too (and is faster).

Comment: Check `mtr.nonzero`code.  It converts `mtr` to `coo`, and returns the row and col attributes (but runs an additional `data!=0` test, in case you set some values to 0 after creating the matrix).

Comment: @hpaulj what happens when this test finds such cases? Shall it throw an error or will it just fix the values 0 deleting them from the matrix?

Comment: Look at its code.  It removes those extra 0s from the arrays that it returns, but does not modify the original matrix.  There is a separate method for cleaning up zeros (`csr_matrix.eliminate_zeros`).  The 'doc' pages have a `[source]` link for each method.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, but I'm a newbie in this topic, not really comfortable reading source. Removing zeros could be a problem, since I intentionally added one zero to the last column of one matrix to align its shape with other matrices I use, since I need to make many point-wise operations on them. What is your advice to deal with it?

Comment: Have you experimented?  The thing I'd watch is the relative length of the `data` and `rows` (and `cols`) arrays.  If `data` has the extra 0s, there might be a mismatch in lengths.  It depends on how or when you added the extra zero.